# Ionic 2, Tab content gets rendered before method execution in main page is completed

Tags: ionic2

I have a dashboard page. and this page has two tabs to show recent sales and recent inventory.
When user inters dashboard, `loadDashboardItems` method is called.

My **dashboard.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, NavParams, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {Storagehelper} from '../../providers/storagehelper';
import { DashboardrecentsalesPage } from '../dashboardrecentsales/dashboardrecentsales';
import { DashboardrecentinventoryPage } from '../dashboardrecentinventory/dashboardrecentinventory';
import {Webservice} from '../../providers/webservice';
/**
 * Generated class for the Dashboard page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@Component({
  selector: 'page-dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
})
export class DashboardPage {
  private recentSales;
  private recentInventory;
  private loading;
  private ajaxRequest;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private storagehelper: Storagehelper, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, public webservice: Webservice) {

      this.loadDashboardItems();


      this.recentSales = DashboardrecentsalesPage; //This is the default tab in dashboard page
      this.recentInventory = DashboardrecentinventoryPage;


  }


  ionViewWillLeave(){
    if(this.loading) this.loading.dismiss().catch(() => {});

    if(this.ajaxRequest!=undefined){
        this.ajaxRequest.unsubscribe();
    }
  }



  private loadDashboardItems(){
      //HERE API REQUEST IS MADE AND data is saved to Localstorage

  }

}
```

And default tab  **dashboardrecentsales.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, Tabs } from 'ionic-angular';
import {Storagehelper} from '../../providers/storagehelper';
/**
 * Generated class for the Dashboardsummaryitems page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@Component({
  selector: 'page-dashboardrecentsales',
  templateUrl: 'dashboardrecentsales.html',
})
export class DashboardrecentsalesPage {
      private RecentItems;

      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private storagehelper: Storagehelper) {
            this.getDashboardItems();
      }

      getDashboardItems(){
            this.RecentItems = this.storagehelper.getStorageItem("RecentItems");
            //This RecentItems property is used to render view dashboardrecentsales
      }



}
```

Here in `dashboard.ts` the API request is made and data are saved in `LocalStorage`

And 'dashboardrecentsales.ts' fetches data from local storage and renders view to show on tab.

**PROBLEM**

The problem I have is if user is accessing `dashboard` page for the first time, Even though data are saved in localstorage, the tab page doesn't get any data from localstorage.

It seems Tab is rendered before execution of `loadDashboardItems` method of dashboard page gets completed.

I tried putting

```
this.recentSales = DashboardrecentsalesPage; //This is the default tab in dashboard page
      this.recentInventory = DashboardrecentinventoryPage;
```

inside `loadDashboardItems` method when everything is saved to localstorage, but no tab view was rendered at all.

Can anybody suggest what can I do in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway I solved it using `event.publish` and `event.subscribe`. More info [Here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/)

The sample code from the link. I used this logic to refresh the contents.

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

// first page (publish an event when a user is created)
constructor(public events: Events) {}
createUser(user) {
  console.log('User created!')
  events.publish('user:created', user, Date.now());
}


// second page (listen for the user created event after function is called)
constructor(public events: Events) {
  events.subscribe('user:created', (user, time) => {
    // user and time are the same arguments passed in `events.publish(user, time)`
    console.log('Welcome', user, 'at', time);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your case, you can make use of ionViewDidLoad() to load your dashboard items. Try something like this,

```
ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.loadDashboardItems();
}
```

check [this documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/) to know more about all the predefined NavController methods

Hope that helps!

Comment: Already tried that, doesn't work. Tab still gets rendered before `loadDashboardItems()` execution completes.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? Create a provider, load your api data there and bring in the data to whatever page you need